# ReplicaSet Primary not showing data

Tags: mongodb

we are using MongoDB 2.4.6 version .

Made  a replicaSet with one Primary , Secondary and an arbitery server .

(The Primary is on serverA and where as Secondary , arbitery  are on  another serverB )

The issue i am facing is that :

1. I killed all Primary , Secondary and arbitery  on serverA and serverB .
2. Then Logged into ServerB and  started Primary mongo
3. Finally Logged into ServerA and  started Secondary and Arbitery mongo instances.

On ServerB under my db (database schema ) is empty (there is no data present under my db)

Could you please let me know why there isn't any data  being shown in serverB even though its primary .

**Edited Part :**

```
> rs.conf()
null
> rs.status()
{
    "startupStatus" : 3,
    "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)"
}
>
```

Comment: Could you post output from `rs.status()`

Comment: @zero323 , i have included the rs.conf and rs.status() in the question under Edited Part .